# MySQL Index being ignored by window function dense_rank

Tags: mysql, database, query-optimization, dense-rank

I'm trying to optimize a query which sets the values of a column storing the order position number which is the position of the given order as viewed from the user's account, based on the order create time.

Setup looks like this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE orders (
    department_id BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    order_hash CHAR(32) NOT NULL,
    account_hash CHAR(32) NOT NULL,
    create_time INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    order_position_number INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    PRIMARY KEY (department_id, order_hash),
    INDEX fk_orders_account_idx (department_id, account_hash),
    INDEX create_time_idx (department_id ASC, create_time ASC),
    INDEX position_number_idx (department_id, account_hash, create_time ASC),
    INDEX test_wo_dep_position_number_idx (account_hash, create_time ASC)
) ENGINE = InnoDB DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8mb4;

INSERT INTO orders 
(department_id, order_hash, account_hash, create_time)
VALUES 
(1, "order_hash_1", "account_hash_1", 100),
(1, "order_hash_2", "account_hash_2", 102),
(1, "order_hash_3", "account_hash_1", 104),
(1, "order_hash_4", "account_hash_1", 101),
(1, "order_hash_5", "account_hash_2", 101),
(1, "order_hash_6", "account_hash_1", 109),
(2, "order_hash_7", "account_hash_1", 107),
(2, "order_hash_8", "account_hash_1", 106);
```

The full query which will be run to populate the `order_position_number` column for the first department is:

```sql
INSERT INTO orders
    (department_id,
     order_hash,
     account_hash,
     order_position_number
    )
SELECT department_id,
        order_hash,
        account_hash,
        DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY account_hash ORDER BY create_time) - 1 AS order_position_number
    FROM orders
    WHERE department_id = 1
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    order_position_number = VALUES(order_position_number);
```

When the INSERT statement is run the performance is very poor.

I've run EXPLAIN on the INSERT query but it is not very helpful.  This is the output:

```json
{
  "query_block": {
    "select_id": 1,
    "cost_info": {
      "query_cost": "6.85"
    },
    "table": {
      "insert": true,
      "select_id": 1,
      "table_name": "orders",
      "access_type": "ALL"
    }
  }
}
```

When EXPLAIN is run on only the SELECT there is more information which indicates the order_position indices are not being used (see `using_filesort`):

```json
{
  "query_block": {
    "select_id": 1,
    "cost_info": {
      "query_cost": "6.85"
    },
    "windowing": {
      "windows": [
        {
          "name": "<unnamed window>",
          "using_filesort": true,
          "filesort_key": [
            "`account_hash`",
            "`create_time`"
          ],
          "functions": [
            "dense_rank"
          ]
        }
      ],
      "cost_info": {
        "sort_cost": "6.00"
      },
      "table": {
        "table_name": "orders",
        "access_type": "ref",
        "possible_keys": [
          "PRIMARY",
          "fk_orders_account_idx",
          "create_time_idx",
          "position_number_idx",
          "test_wo_dep_position_number_idx"
        ],
        "key": "PRIMARY",
        "used_key_parts": [
          "department_id"
        ],
        "key_length": "8",
        "ref": [
          "const"
        ],
        "rows_examined_per_scan": 6,
        "rows_produced_per_join": 6,
        "filtered": "100.00",
        "cost_info": {
          "read_cost": "0.25",
          "eval_cost": "0.60",
          "prefix_cost": "0.85",
          "data_read_per_join": "1K"
        },
        "used_columns": [
          "department_id",
          "order_hash",
          "account_hash",
          "create_time"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

When EXPLAIN ANALYZE is run on the SELECT query, there is more information indicating that the index is not being used for the sort operation within the window.

```
-> Window aggregate: dense_rank() OVER (PARTITION BY orders.account_hash ORDER BY orders.create_time )   (actual time=0.043..0.046 rows=6 loops=1)
    -> Sort: orders.account_hash, orders.create_time  (cost=0.85 rows=6) (actual time=0.036..0.037 rows=6 loops=1)
        -> Index lookup on orders using PRIMARY (department_id=1)  (actual time=0.016..0.021 rows=6 loops=1)
```

When the target query is run on a large orders table the performance is very poor.
The documentation regarding optimization of RANK window functions is very rare so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: the select uses the primary key nothing is faster, the on duplicate and the window function will need time, that you can not optimize

Comment: Why are you doing this as IODKU instead of a normal UPDATE query?

Comment: There are multiple procedures which update the table and they can effect the same rows. But my interest is optimizing the select with the window function. It's been hard finding documentation on this.

Comment: How many rows in the table?  How many rows are being modified?